# Change site path on Yii Framework

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii

I need to change Yii web app path.

I Installed Yii framework on this path
.. htdocs\anasii\

and I created webapp in this path

.. htdocs\anasii\anasii

my site path now is:

http://anasii.com/anasii/

How can me change this path to:

http://anasii.com/

I used .htaccess and httpd.config and I set config file like this 'urlFormat'=>'path'.
What steps remain ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get it work, i've put my site folder in htdocs directly so its path is /htdocs/mysite .. regarding the Yii source , copying the framework folder from it into my site folder (next to media , protected , .. folders) then changing **index.php** as Adrin said to:

```
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
```

Should do it no matter where you move it.
More over you need to edit **.htaccess** of your site to include this:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Since your site is in a folder and not directly on htdocs

Ofcourse you will need to configure your **httpd.conf** to the new paths of your site too.

Comment: It' work now after I changed DocumentRoot link in VirtualHost from httpd-vhost

Answer (score 0):

In the main directory of you yii install there is the index.php which contains these two paths

```
// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
```

Comment: thx man but not work.. new links is work but links in page doesn't work